# CGShadingGetBounds() signature?

Tags: macos, assembly, reverse-engineering, quartz-graphics

I am trying to get the signature of method CGShadingGetBounds()?

I tried, `CG_EXTERN CGRect CGShadingGetBounds(CGShadingRef);` but it does not seem to be a case.

Can someone help figure out the signature?
Below is the disassembly.

```
__text:000000000016BB76                 public _CGShadingGetBounds
__text:000000000016BB76 _CGShadingGetBounds proc near           ; CODE XREF: _log_LogShading+1B8p
__text:000000000016BB76                                         ; _dlr_DrawShading+1FEp ...
__text:000000000016BB76                 push    rbp
__text:000000000016BB77                 mov     rbp, rsp
__text:000000000016BB7A                 mov     rax, rdi
__text:000000000016BB7D                 cmp     byte ptr [rsi+28h], 0
__text:000000000016BB81                 jz      short loc_16BBAC
__text:000000000016BB83                 movsd   xmm0, qword ptr [rsi+30h]
__text:000000000016BB88                 movsd   qword ptr [rdi], xmm0
__text:000000000016BB8C                 movsd   xmm0, qword ptr [rsi+38h]
__text:000000000016BB91                 movsd   qword ptr [rdi+8], xmm0
__text:000000000016BB96                 movsd   xmm0, qword ptr [rsi+40h]
__text:000000000016BB9B                 movsd   qword ptr [rdi+10h], xmm0
__text:000000000016BBA0                 movsd   xmm0, qword ptr [rsi+48h]
__text:000000000016BBA5
__text:000000000016BBA5 loc_16BBA5:                             ; CODE XREF: _CGShadingGetBounds+5Ej
__text:000000000016BBA5                 movsd   qword ptr [rdi+18h], xmm0
__text:000000000016BBAA                 pop     rbp
__text:000000000016BBAB                 retn
__text:000000000016BBAC ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__text:000000000016BBAC
__text:000000000016BBAC loc_16BBAC:                             ; CODE XREF: _CGShadingGetBounds+Bj
__text:000000000016BBAC                 lea     rcx, _CGRectInfinite
__text:000000000016BBB3                 movsd   xmm0, qword ptr [rcx]
__text:000000000016BBB7                 movsd   xmm1, qword ptr [rcx+8]
__text:000000000016BBBC                 movsd   qword ptr [rdi], xmm0
__text:000000000016BBC0                 movsd   qword ptr [rdi+8], xmm1
__text:000000000016BBC5                 movsd   xmm0, qword ptr [rcx+10h]
__text:000000000016BBCA                 movsd   qword ptr [rdi+10h], xmm0
__text:000000000016BBCF                 movsd   xmm0, qword ptr [rcx+18h]
__text:000000000016BBD4                 jmp     short loc_16BBA5
__text:000000000016BBD4 _CGShadingGetBounds endp
```

My aim is to identify the bounds in which shading is going to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the signature you mentioned

```
CG_EXTERN CGRect CGShadingGetBounds(CGShadingRef);
```

is correct. For example if you try to reconstruct such function with a custom object, like this:

```
typedef struct
{
    long a1, a2, a3, a4, a5;
    char b6;
    CGRect r;
} MyObj;

CGRect ReconstructFunc(MyObj *o)
{
    if (o->b6) return o->r;
    return CGRectNull;
}
```

of course, this does something different, but the "quick" path (where b6 is non-zero) is very very similar to the original function, in both assembly and in behaviour:

```
pushq   %rbp
movq    %rsp, %rbp
movq    %rdi, %rax
cmpb    $0, 40(%rsi)
je  LBB0_2
movq    72(%rsi), %rcx
movq    %rcx, 24(%rax)
movq    64(%rsi), %rcx
movq    %rcx, 16(%rax)
movq    48(%rsi), %rcx
movq    56(%rsi), %rdx
movq    %rdx, 8(%rax)
movq    %rcx, (%rax)
popq    %rbp
ret
    ... (continues)
```

This is basically the same at the assembly you posted. It also implies some "convention" obj-c and Mac GCC uses for compiling methods with CGRect structs. According to the [x64 ABI](http://x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf) parameters are passed in these registers: RDI, RSI, RDX, (and more). If you take a look at the first two, RDI and RSI, they clearly contains arguments, first one is a pointer to the output struct (CGRect), second one is the opaque struct (CGShadingReg).

Thus I believe that GCC on Mac translates this:

```
CGRect myrect = MyFuncReturningRect(param);
```

into this:

```
CGRect myrect;
MyFuncReturningRect(&myrect, param);
```

Anyway to sum it all up, I strongly believe your guessed signature is correct. If the function doesn't return values you expect, it is caused by some other factors (probably by the `byte ptr [rsi+28h]` value, which must be non-null to get some non-dummy information).